# How to Initialize those entities in C# using OOP?

Tags: c#, oop

What is the perfect initialization design pattern for those classes?

First class called Client that has name, ID and list of orders "that he bought".

Second class called DeliveryReceptionist, his class has his name, his ID and list of orders he bought and the list of persons he serve.

Third class is the items he buy, I have a list of 10 items and each item should have a name and ID

Forth class is the order which consists of the item_ID, price of each item, number of items "as each order has one type of items".

It's weird and not applied to real life, but it is not me that put it.

So I've tried that:

```
public class Information
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public class Client : Information
{
    List<theOrder> orders = new List<theOrder>();
}

public class DelRec : Information
{
    List<Client> listOfClients = new List<Client>();
    List<theOrder> orders = new List<theOrder>();
}

public static class items
{
    public static List<Information> item = new List<Information>();
}

public class theOrder
{
    private int itemID { get; set; }
    private double price { get; set; }
    private double number { get; set; }
}
```

Is that good? Or I should optimize it in a better way?

Comment: You already have great OOP style aswer. But I'd like to ask which part of system you want to create. I mean is it something related to order processing, so orders and clients already stored and delivery receptionist need to go through this orders and send it to customers.
Or it's a customer goes to shop and choose products he want to bought?
Thous parts of system will be implemented differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that i would about this code.

All Properties and classes should be PascalCase in C#.
theOrder should be Order as it is type not instance, You can call an instance theOrder if you like.
There is no way to instantiate the properties of Order class if you make them private and have empty constructor. Also how will you use the getters?

You will need constructors to initialize your properties.
And also it is good OOP to create interfaces and abstract classes.
To begin with, my code would be something like:

```
public interface IPerson
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Id { get; }
}

public interface ISalesSubject : IPerson
{
    IDictionary<int, IOrder> Orders { get; }
}

public abstract class SalesSubject: ISalesSubject
{
    protected SalesSubject(string name, int id)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Id = id;
        this.Orders = new Dictionary<int, IOrder>();
    }

    protected SalesSubject(string name, int id, IDictionary<int, IOrder> orders)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Id = id;
        this.Orders = orders;
    }

    public string Name { get; protected set; }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }

    public IDictionary<int, IOrder> Orders { get; protected set; }

    public virtual void AddOrder(int itemId, IOrder order)
    {
        if (!this.Orders.ContainsKey(itemId))
        {
            this.Orders.Add(itemId, order);
        }
    }

    public virtual void RemoveOrder(int itemId, IOrder order)
    {
        this.Orders.Remove(itemId, order);
    }
}

public class Client : SalesSubject
{

    public Client(string name, int id)
        : base(name, id)
    {
        this.Orders = new Dictionary<int, IOrder>();
    }

    public Client(string name, int id, IDictionary<int, IOrder> orders)
        : base(name, id, orders)
    {
        this.Orders = orders;
    }
}

public class DeliveryReceptionist : SalesSubject
{
    public DeliveryReceptionist(string name, int id)
        : base(name, id)
    {
        this.Clients = new Dictionary<int, Client>();
    }

    public DeliveryReceptionist(string name, int id, IDictionary<int, IOrder> orders)
        : base(name, id, orders)
    {
        this.Clients = new Dictionary<int, Client>();
    }

    public DeliveryReceptionist(string name, int id, IDictionary<int, IOrder> orders, IDictionary<int, Client> clients)
       : base(name, id, orders)
    {
        this.Clients = clients;
    }

    public DeliveryReceptionist(string name, int id, IDictionary<int, Client> clients)
       : base(name, id)
    {
        this.Clients = clients;
    }

    public IDictionary<int, Client> Clients { get; set; }

    public void AddClient(int clientId, Client client)
    {
        if (!this.Clients.ContainsKey(clientId))
        {
            this.Clients.Add(clientId, client);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveClient(int clientId, Client client)
    {
        this.Clients.Remove(clientId, client);
    }
}

public interface IOrder
{
    int ItemID { get; set; }
    double Price { get; set; }
    double Number { get; set; }
}
public class Order : IOrder
{
    public Order(int itemId, double price, double number)
    {
        this.ItemId = itemId;
        this.Price = price;
        this.Number = number;
    }

    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public double Number { get; set; }
}
```

Why do you need items class.Static classes are anti-pattern when talking about encapsualtion and good OOP.They can be accessed from anywhere and its content changed if it is with public access modificator.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you that the code should be in PascalCase and "theOrder" doesn't need the " I added that while testing thing and forget to remove it, and also by mistake I edited the code here before posting the question to clarify the code so I've also forgot to change private into public for those properties. So I can't agree more with you in those things.
About the item class, it's required and I don't know what to do else, I have to add some items and display them, How can I do that, with empty inheritance class? i really don't know.

Comment: lastly, I'm not so familiar with dictionaries, so could you please in one time show how can I for example add order or client? thanks a lot

Comment: var orderId = 1;var price = 20.5;
            var number = 20;
            Order order = new Order(orderId, price, number);
            var clientName = "Omar";
            var clientId = 100;
            var client = new Client(clientName, clientId);
            client.AddOrder(orderId, order);
            var delRecId = 1;
            var delRecName = "Postman";
            var delRec = new DeliveryReceptionist(delRecName, delRecId);
            delRec.AddClient(clientId, client);
            delRec.RemoveClient(clientId);
            client.RemoveOrder(orderId);

Comment: This is purely hypothetically, because i do not know how you generate order or client, or delivery receptionist information.

Comment: You can use repository pattern for storing data about clients and/or delivery receptionists and printing it on demand. Also for orders.

Comment: In your repository you can have the
following collections.
In case you need to access all orders by client you can create Dictionary<Client, Order> ordersByClient;
In case you need to access regularly all orders by delivery receptionist you can create Dictionary<DeliveryReceptionist, IOrder> ordersByDelRec
Also you can create ISet<Client> clients, ISet<DeliveryReceptionist, IOrder> delivermen, ISet<IOrder> orders
In the repository you can create methods for adding to and removing from those collections, and methods for printing information directly or custom sorted.